# Why scroll on modal/popup doesn't working on instagram

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, instagram

Im so embarrassed because i doesn't scroll on a modal in instagram. Instead of that it scrolling the page on the back :(

i already try with `browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", modalDiv)`  ...i try with any thing i founded but still not work.

My code :

```
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/%s' % account)
sleep(2)

clickToFollowing= browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/span")
clickToFollowing.click()

actionChain = webdriver.ActionChains(browser)
time.sleep(2)

modalDiv= browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 660);")
```

[image]

Comment: Check out for iframe

Comment: @cruisepandey how i can made that ??

Comment: you don't have to make them, it's just the you have to identify in developer tool (F12) that element or elements are inside the iframe or not, if yes then you would have to switch to that frame in order to have interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scroll multiple time in follower list section to grab everything you need.

**Code :**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\etc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"username"))).send_keys('your username')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"password"))).send_keys('your password')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[type='submit']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
sleep(3)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[text()='Not Now']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Activity Feed']/../../following-sibling::div/span"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Profile']"))).click()
sleep(3)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Change Profile Photo']/../../../following-sibling::section/descendant::li[3]/a"))).click()
sleep(3)
fBody  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")
scroll = 0
while scroll < 5: # scroll 5 times
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    sleep(2)
    scroll += 1

fList  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']//li")
print("fList len is {}".format(len(fList)))
print("ended")
```